# VB.NET Copy To Clipboard Error

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

[image: Problem]

I really don't know what is going on. I used this code a lot of times, but for my current project I can't copy anything to clipboard without Catch ex As Exception which I don't like it cause it take so long until the content is copied to clipboard.

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: When you click on View Detail and look at the inner exception what is that telling you?

Comment: I found the problem. The clipboard were used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your application as Administrator or open your Visual Studio IDE with option Run as administrator.

Comment: I'm always running it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to tell the type of data format you want to copy into Clipboard, after changing the text.

```
Clipboard.SetText("df", TextDataFormat.Text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you answer one question, please comment it a little bit. Eve if it is right

Comment: thanks for the advice I will pay attention to it in the future

Comment: You should take the advice given and apply it to **this** post!